# read white space character from txt file in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a code that used "good" function for reading characters one by one from a txt file in c++.
the "good" function can not read white spaces. so I need a function like good, but it can read white spaces and every characters one by one.
this is part of my code:

```
char *s=NULL;
char str1;

ifstream text_file("Hello.txt");
text_file >> str1;
s= &str1;
do
{
    cout << "*s1 " << *s <<endl;
    text_file >> str1;
    s= &str1;
} while(text_file.good());


text_file.close();
```

Comment: I found the true answer! txt_fie.get(c) can get every characters such as whitespace!! any way thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the whitespace skipper

```
text_file >> std::noskipws;
```

Comment: your answer is exactly against my request!